# Img isn't showing full width of the table

Tags: css, html

I am trying to put the banner image in the full header `<div>` of [this page](http://idc.interlinktravels.com/lanka/default7.aspx).

So for this I have tried the following code:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="Images/CA Banner_Final.jpg"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

But the image is displaying in only a portion of the `<div>`. How can I fit it to full width of the `<div>`.

Comment: instead of using `img` tag use CSS feature like `background image` and repeat it on `x-axis`

Comment: Your image is small for the div and don't use tables. It's not standard for your usage.

Comment: @ManojKumar Can you prove with link that `<table>` is deprecated?

Comment: @ManojKumar you are wrong. Tables are still valid and used in some cases. for more read [MDN], (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

Comment: @Justinas I meant to say, it was not standard for this usage.

Comment: Nope still wrong... have you ever worked on Finance based web applications?

Comment: give `width:100%` to table and img.

Comment: @KheemaPandey I know table is used in many cases. But why would he use table for showing an image over a div. I remembered showing an image within table when vBulletin was used in 2000s. Give me the link to the finance apps though.

Comment: aahh those are closed web based app.. A login must required..

Comment: you might be right, but without knowing actual context you can not comeup at any conclusion...

Comment: Yeah that's right Kheema, I will need to correct my usage of words :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are wraping image into table structure?

you can simply put it into `.content-wrapper` div

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <img src="http://idc.interlinktravels.com/lanka/Images/CA%20Banner_Final.jpg">
</div>
```

**css**

```
.content-wrapper img {
    width:100%
}
```

If you want a wrapper Div around the image within content-wrapper then try following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ejgt2syy/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="banner">
        <img src="http://idc.interlinktravels.com/lanka/Images/CA%20Banner_Final.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.banner img {
    width:100%
}
```

Comment: ...I did the changes but now the Image is blurred!!! Why its coming so should I adjust the height also?

Comment: ofcourse it will be blurred bcz in this case you are stretching the image from their normal width...either use much higher resolution image or use one part of image and call image from the `background` property

Comment: No, Your image is small, and we are trying to stretch it to match the width. thats why it is getting blurred. if we change width of the image. height is getting changed in proportion with the appropriate width.

Comment: @user3305327: What Kheema Pandey is suggesting is absolutely correct. you can go for higher resolution image.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <img class="full_width" src="Images/CA Banner_Final.jpg">   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.full_width{
    width:100%;
}
```

there is no need for tables, so I removed that code